# Google Analytics - Realtime data not available for host name filter

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We have integrated GA4 code in our web application for both prod and non-prod applications.
We are trying to get the seggerated user's traffic for prod and non-prod URL's in realtime.
prod URL: https://test.com
non-prod URL: https://test-dev.com

I accessed the prod URL and in real-time reporting applied the hostname filter for the prod URL, but I cannot see the traffic in the same, it shows the traffic in "all users".

[image]

Is this the BUG? or am I missing any steps here??

Thanks,

Abhishek

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to filter on Hostname in GA4 Realtime.

Your reports show three comparisons: 1) All Users, 2) Hostname includes the prod URL, and 3) Hostname includes the non-prod URL. No data is available for the second two reports. If you scroll down, there are "No data available" messages for the other cards. Example:

[image]

One solution is to tag your prod site and non-prod site to different web data streams in one GA4 property. Then, you could compare the different streams in the Realtime Reports.

[The Google Analtyics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/realtime-api-schema) has a list of most of the dimensions & metric available in Realtime. For example, Hostname is not on the list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Brett.
So then If I create 2 Data-Streams, I will have to have 2 different measurement IDs for Prod and Non-Prod sites.
I want the Tags to be the same for both the sites, I am ok with NOT getting the real-time report for prod and non-prod, as I am getting the users count in the traffic acquisition report.

Thanks,
ABhishek

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Stream ID as a proxy for hostname, but only if you've got a stream for each of the environments.